# "Unable to find build script" error running Ant from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, junit, ant

I got this error when running Jenkins to build an Ant project. Could someone explain the source of the problem and how to fix it?

```
ERROR: Unable to find build script at D:\WORK\06_HRMS\90_SourceCode\trunk\jwf
Recording test results
Injecting SonarQube environment variables using the configuration: Sonar
ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ aborted due to exception: 
java.io.IOException: Failed to read /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MBFS/lib/CopyLibs/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
Is this really a JUnit report file? Your configuration must be matching too many files
```